# Storing a translation dictionary

Tags: android, json, database

I want to make an app that shows the user words and he then has to write what the word means in a different language. Now I of course have to "store" all the words and their meanings somehow. Would a json file like this be good?

Or should I use something else?

```
{"words:": [
   { 
    "german" : "fahrrad",
    "english" : "bike",
   }

   { 
    next word...
   }

   { 
    next word...
   }

 ]}
```

Comment: See the Android docs: [Saving Data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) in the getting started guide and [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in the API guides. A Google search for "_android persistent data_" will turn up these and many other useful resources for you.

Comment: you may want to avoid using "german" and "english" and instead use java locales : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an absolute single best way to store data in your Android application.  It all comes down to what your application is doing/using the data for.  How will new data be added, will all the CRUD operation be implemented, etc.

Here's the [Android Developers guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to data storage, you have several options:

- Shared Preferences
- Internal/External Storage
- SQLite Databases
- Network Connection

You'll have to do some research on which fit is best for your application.  I'd recommend SQLite just from what you've mentioned though.  Should be the easiest to store a large amount of data and make it simple to add/remove/edit the data.

Here's the [Android Developer's training](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) on Saving Data if various formats.

Answer (score 0):

I would say an [SQLite database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) would be much better.

Comment: I don't think a SQLite database would be good at all... You have a word and potentially infinite translations. You cannot define a table schema for that

Comment: Well, it's going to be kind of clunky, but you can search it really easily. And you can just alter the table everytime you need to add another language. You would have to rewrite the entire JSON if that happened.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, though. Altering the table for new languages. So, are you suggesting you have one column for (English, Spanish, French, German, etc.), then if you want to add Portuguese, you'd alter the entire table?

Comment: Well, yea... when you add one extra language you have to alter the entire JSON file as well.

Comment: Not necessarily. If using a NoSQL database, for example, you just append a new key-value into the document

Comment: That's true. Now I guess the question is, how performance intensive would altering a table with a couple hundred thousand records be.

Comment: @cricket_007 - I'm not saying that an SQLite solution is best (it may or may not be, depending on what OP needs), but why on earth couldn't one define a data base schema for that? It probably couldn't be in a single table, but SQLite handles multi-table data bases just fine. One table for valid languages, another for terms (possibly just a term ID), and a cross-product table for (term x language) translations. Easy.

Comment: @TedHopp Cross joins would get messy, in my opinion. And what would be the primary key that you "translate from"? Your native language? `SELECT g.id, g.word FROM english e JOIN german g ON e.id = g.id`, for example, just could be better represented in another form, was my point.

Comment: @cricket_007 - If you think I'm suggesting a table for `english` and another one for `german`, you don't get what I'm talking about at all. You'd have a table for `language`, another for `term`, and a third for `termInLanguage`. How you use them depends on the query. It's not clear that OP even wants to support a "translate from" operations, but it could easily be accommodated (probably in a single SQL query). Also, what other storage method are you going to suggest, particularly if you want to avoid having to load hundreds of thousands of records into memory at once?

Comment: @TedHopp As I suggested a NoSQL database. For an embedded one, then possibly Realm or Couchbase Lite.